# Control a C920 Logitech HD Pro Webcam using C under linux

Tags: c, linux, webcam, logitech

Is their any C api to control C920 Logitech HD Pro Webcam.The Cam came with a controller under windows to control its directions and can track a human face, I need to do the same using C under linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post so maybe it's no longer relevant.  Also IANA expert...  But apparently this webcam is UVC compatible, so the UVC driver would be the place to look.  I have one and it does work on my Ubuntu 12 64-bit system (although it disappears every time the system goes to sleep).